# Comparing Items in two ObservableCollections

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have two ObservableCollections, one that contains a current list of employees and one that contains a new one. If the new one contains an employee that is not in the old list, I want to add it to the old list.

If the new list does not contain an employee in the old list, I want to remove it from the old list. (I hope that makes sense).

Here is what I have tried;

```
foreach (var employee in _currentUsers.ToList())
{
    if (!newUsers.Contains(employee))
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            _currentUsers.Remove(employee);
            CurrentUsageDataGrid.Items.Refresh();                      
        });
    }
}

foreach (var employee in newUsers)
{
    if (!_currentUsers.Contains(employee))
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            _currentUsers.Add(employee);
            CurrentUsageDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        });
    }
}
```

This is not working as even when I know that the lists haven't changed the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` is still firing. Am I misunderstanding how `Contains` operates and/or is there a 'better' way of performing a check like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your employee class implement `IEquatable<T>` interface, the method Contains of `ObservableCollection` will use `Equal` in that interface to compare object.
Otherwise you may need to use Linq to check for existing employee instead of using `Contains`

More reference on MSDN, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned above you need to implement/override an Equal method for the comparison. When you do a "Contains" check on 2 class objects, it checks if the 2 objects are equal (not if their properties are). You can do the equal using an id, or you could compute a hashvalue and compare those.